# Creating a factory function inside an already created object (JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, object, javascript-objects

I'm very new to JavaScript, and while doing a practice exercise where I had to create three objects inside an array that was inside an object (Sounds weird while typing), I was wondering if I could use factory functions which I had learned previously to maybe speed this process up.

While researching about factory functions, I didn't really get an answer to my question, which was: **Can one use factory functions inside an already created object?**

What I want to create is:

Object - Array - Factory function to add more objects to the array.

When I create said factory function, it doesn't return any errors, but I'm unable to call the function to create more objects.

Do I need to call it differently because it is inside an array, rather than a "normal object"?

This is what I have:

```
const team = {
 _players: [

{firstName: "Brogan", lastName: "Harrell", age: 20},
{firstName: "Laila", lastName: "Chavez", age: 21},
{firstName: "Rocco", lastName: "Kennedy", age: 30},
  ],

_games: [

/*
{opponent: "opponent1", teamPoints: 50, opponentPoints: 100},
{opponent: "opponent2", teamPoints: 100, opponentPoints: 200},
{opponent: "opponent3", teamPoints: 150, opponentPoints: 300},

*/


function gameFactory(opponent, teamPoints, opponentPoints) {
  return {
    opponent: opponent,
    teamPoints: teamPoints,
    opponentPoints: opponentPoints,
         }
  }  
 ],
};
```

I then try to call this factory function as such:

```
const firstOpponent = team._games.gameFactory("opponent1", 50, 100);

const secondOpponent = team._games.gameFactory("opponent2", 100, 200);

const thirdOpponent = team._games.gameFactory("opponent3", 150, 300);

console.log(firstGame)

console.log(secondGame)

console.log(thirdGame)
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: team._games.gameFactory is not a function
```

Naturally, I went researching for the causes that this error can be triggered by.

The causes were:

**A typo in the function name** (not the case)

**Function called on the wrong object** (also believe this is not the case, as I've read that factory functions are just functions used to create something.)

**Function shares a name with a pre-existing property** (not the case)

So, am I trying to do something impossible or am I wrongfully calling the function?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In your declaration, you have `[` and `]` right before and after the function, so your `team._games` is an array. So you should either use it like `team._games[0]("opponent1", 50, 100)` or change your object definition

Comment: @qrsngky Yes, it's an array. It's part of the exercise to be an array, so I can't change it. However, if I followed your suggestion, how do I pass the parameters so I can create more objects to that array?

Edit: Just saw your edit, going to try it.

Comment: @qrsngky Got it, now I can see what I wanted. It was just a matter of properly passing parameters since it was a function inside an array. Thank you very much :).

Comment: It's a matter of accessing the function (the parameters are unchanged); your function is found at `team._games[0]` instead of `team._games.gameFactory` (the key `gameFactory` is undefined for a regular array).
However, the code looks a bit odd so I just wonder if the `[` and `]` were added by mistake.